# Finding $c$ given $a, ab, abc$ are in A.P

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

> If a, b, c are distinct nonzero integers such that a, ab, abc are in A.P then find the value of c.
>   The answer is one among this : 1, 2, 3 or 4.

I tried $$\frac{a+abc}{2}=ab$$ 
But solving doesn't seem to give a numerical answer independent of b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation becomes $1+bc=2b$  If $b \neq \pm 1$ the right side is divisible by $b$ and the left is not, so those are the only choices for $b$.  We can just try them both.  If $b=1$ we have $1+c=2$, which requires $c=1$ but $b,c$ are distinct, so $b=-1, 1-c=-2, c=3$.  We cannot find $a$, but were not asked to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by $2/(ab)$ gives
$$\frac1b+ c=2$$
for this to be an integer $b$ had better be $1$ or $-1$ etc.

Comment: So, can be both 1 and 3 ?

Comment: @HGSur I'd say that $c=1$ and $c=3$ are both possibilities that warrant further investigation.

Comment: I got it now as Ross said, in question it is given that b and c are distinct so b cannot be 1.